# Null при добавление элемента в массив в массиве

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

У меня есть кастомный класс массива, внутри которого есть еще один кастомный класс другого массива.

Основной класс:

```
public class MyGamesClass {

private String platform;
private String title;
private String price;
private String img;
private String purchasedDate;
private String format;
private boolean sale;
private String saleDate;
private String salePrice;
private boolean passed;
private String passedDate;
private ArrayList <MyDlcClass> dlc;
private String dlcUrl;
private String russian;
private String cooperative;
private String online;
private String url;

...
}
```

Дочерний класс:

```
public class MyDlcClass {

private String title;
private String date;
private String img;
private String url;
...
}
```

Есть массив `myGames<MyGamesClass>` в который элементы добавляются по типу

```
MyGames.myGames.add(new MyGamesClass(
    getIntent.getStringExtra("PLATFORM_KEY"), title.getText().toString(),
    price.getText().toString(), getIntent.getStringExtra("IMG_KEY"),
    date.getText().toString(), formatFinal, false, null,
    null,false, null,null,
    getIntent.getStringExtra("DLCURL_KEY"), russianFinal, coopFinal,
    onlineFinal, getIntent.getStringExtra("URL_KEY")

     ));
```

На место `ArrayList <MyDlcClass> dlc`по умолчанию ставится `null`. И вот когда я хочу добавить в `ArrayList <MyDlcClass> dlc` массив по типу

```
MyGames.myGames.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION_KEY", 0))
        .getDlc()
        .add(new MyDlcClass(
        allDlc.get(position).getTitle(), "тест даты", allDlc.get(position).getImg(), allDlc.get(position).getUrl()
               ));
```

на выходе я получаю ошибку на строке `.add(new MyDlcClass(`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

По дебагеру я вижу, что все данные вставляются в массив как нужно, но на последнем этапе, когда все элементы собраны, я получаю ошибку.

Что делать?

Comment: В какой-то момент у вас вот эта строка `MyGames.myGames.get(getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION_KEY", 0))
        .getDlc()` возвращает null поэтому ошибка `"Попытка вызвать виртуальный метод '...ArrayList.add()' на null-объекте"`

Comment: переменная массива инициализирована?

Comment: Jarvis, в каком смысле? Она в классе массива. У меня в другом проекте есть кастомный класс массива, внутри которого есть Обычный строковый массив, и там текущая схема добавления в него элементов работает.

Comment: Где-то (в конструкторе например) должно быть так `dlc = new ArrayList<MyDlcClass>()`

Comment: Jarvis, да, массив не пустой и инициализирован (восстанавливается из SharedPreferences).

Comment: Alexander Chernin, спасибо, навели на верную мысль. Сейчас напишу в ответе.

Comment: @АртемИльинский, наверняка обращение происходит раньше инициализации.

Answer (score 3):

У вас массив не инициализирован.

Вот вод здесь вы даёте значения для массива *null* :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом вы пытаетесь добавить объект в не инициализированный массив.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было в конструкторе заменить

```
public ArrayList<MyDlcClass> getDlc() {
        return dlc;
    }
```

на

```
public ArrayList<MyDlcClass> getDlc() {
    if (dlc == null) {
        return dlc = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        return dlc;
    }
}
```

Так как возвращался null из-за неинициализированного ранее массива. Возможно, это костыль, но работает.

Comment: он так у вас каждый раз массив обнулять будет. Лучше создайте `new ArrayList<>()` в конструкторе

Comment: Да, уже увидел, поспешил с ответом)))